# Publishing videos and images from blog to facebook

Tags: plugins, facebook

Is there any wordpress plugin for publishing videos and images from blog to respected facebook user's profile wall?

I have a wordpress blog and having 1000+ users. these users will upload images and videos from wp-admin. These uploaded images and videos should be published to their respected facebook user's profile wall.

Please help me if any solution....Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That feature has been removed from Facebook: http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=277347965620183

You could write a script that would log in as the user and post stuff, but that would be violating the Facebook terms of use.

Or you could do it the other way around. Post the stuff on Facebook, and have your Wordpress site grab the data from the relevant Facebook RSS feed. Here is one example: http://isaacadams.com/2011/10/27/how-to-add-your-facebook-status-to-wordpress/

But really, for 1000+ users it might be difficult to setup, so maybe they should do their own legwork and do as Facebook suggests, copy and paste their blog post url into their Facebook status update, and go from there.